# Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" abrir FXML dentro de um AnchorPane

Tags: java, exceção, javafx

Criei um Menu de topo e quero que abre o arquivo FXML correspondente dentro do Anchorpane quando eu clicar em um item do menu. Porém tem dado o seguinte erro: 
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Meu código está da seguinte forma:

TelaInicial.java:

```
package Controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;

import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;



public class TelaInicialController implements Initializable {



    @FXML
    private AnchorPane anchorpane;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem agendarHorario;

    @FXML
    private MenuItem cadastrarNovo;


    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }    


    @FXML
    public void handleabrircadastrar() throws IOException{
        AnchorPane a = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/hairsoft/View/CadastrarCliente.fxml"));
        anchorpane.getChildren().setAll(a);   
    }
}
```

CadastrarCliente.fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="450.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" fx:controller="Controller.CadastrarClienteController">
   <children>
      <SplitPane fx:id="tableInfo" dividerPositions="0.29797979797979796" layoutX="20.0" layoutY="40.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
        <items>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <TableView layoutX="-25.0" layoutY="-10.0" prefHeight="398.0" prefWidth="175.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
                    <columns>
                      <TableColumn fx:id="colunaNome" prefWidth="75.0" text="NOME" />
                      <TableColumn fx:id="colunaCPF" prefWidth="75.0" text="CPF" />
                    </columns>
                     <columnResizePolicy>
                        <TableView fx:constant="CONSTRAINED_RESIZE_POLICY" />
                     </columnResizePolicy>
                  </TableView>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
          <AnchorPane minHeight="0.0" minWidth="0.0" prefHeight="160.0" prefWidth="100.0">
               <children>
                  <GridPane layoutX="46.0" layoutY="109.0" prefHeight="230.0" prefWidth="341.0">
                    <columnConstraints>
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                      <RowConstraints maxHeight="108.0" minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="59.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                      <RowConstraints maxHeight="86.0" minHeight="7.0" prefHeight="56.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                        <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>
                     <children>
                        <Label text="Label" />
                        <Label text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                        <Label text="Label" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                        <Label text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                        <Label text="Label" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                        <Label text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                        <Label text="Label" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                        <Label text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="3" />
                     </children>
                  </GridPane>
               </children>
            </AnchorPane>
        </items>
      </SplitPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

ERRO COMPLETO:

> ```
> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
>     at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
>     at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462)
>     at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1405)
>     at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer.lambda$createChildren$343(ContextMenuContent.java:1358)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
>     at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
>     at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
>     at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
>     at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
>     at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
>     at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
>     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:380)
>     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:294)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354(GlassViewEventHandler.java:416)
>     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
>     at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:415)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
>     at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>     at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
>     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>     at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1771)
>     ... 43 more
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
>     at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
>     at Controller.TelaInicialController.handleabrircadastrar(TelaInicialController.java:38)
>     ... 53 more
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vinha recebendo exatamente o mesmo erro, e resolvi de um modo meio.. nada a ver.
Ao invés de usar esta linha:

```
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Layout.fxml"));
```

Fiz isso:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("Layout.fxml");
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(url);
```

Meio sem lógica, né!? Afinal, o retorno de "getClass().getResource()" já é uma URL.
Porém funcionou perfeitamente. o_O

Answer (score 0):

A causa refere-se a um NPE.

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at Controller.TelaInicialController.handleabrircadastrar(TelaInicialController.java:38)
... 53 more
```

Para a ausência do Location.

Verifica em tempo de debug se realmente está sendo retornado algum objeto na para `getClass().getResource("/hairsoft/View/CadastrarCliente.fxml")` ou se não `null`.

Ponto da falha:

```
  @FXML
public void handleabrircadastrar() throws IOException{
    AnchorPane a = (AnchorPane) FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/hairsoft/View/CadastrarCliente.fxml"));
    anchorpane.getChildren().setAll(a);   
}
```